# MySQL : WHERE table.column(current_date), evaluate an expression if colum's value at today's date equals a specific value

Tags: mysql

thanks in advance for your help .

I'm being stuck as I'd like to filter transactions from users that are currently blocked  but tried to perform a transaction. The problem is that the transactions of people that have been unblocked still show up in the results. So ideally I'd like to show only the transactions of blocked users that have the status 'blocked' at today's date, not the ones that have been unblocked in the meantime.

I have two tables and I'd like to filter by table.column(at date today), I don't know if there's an if statement or ternary expression that would help me evaluate the value of a column at a specific time (today).

```
Table 1 : suspended

| blacklisted   | PHONE      | date_suspended | 
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------
| UNBLOCKED     | +34XXXXXXX | 02-03-19  |    
| BLOCKED       | +34XXXXXXX | 03-05-26  |    
| BLOCKED       | +34XXXXXXX | 23-09-20  |    
| BLOCKED       | +34XXXXXXX | 26-02-18  |    
| UNBLOCKED     | +34XXXXXXX | 15-03-18  |     

Table 2 : transaction

 | PHONE      | transaction_date | 
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| +34XXXXXXX  | 06-03-19  |     
|  +34XXXXXXX | 13-05-26  |     
|  +34XXXXXXX | 23-09-20  |     
|  +34XXXXXXX | 06-02-18  |     
|  +34XXXXXXX | 05-03-18  |     



SELECT S.blacklisted, T.date_transaction 
FROM suspended S INNER JOIN transaction T ON S.phone = T.phone
WHERE IF(S.blacklisted(current_date) like '%blocked%')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please learn https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and show us your table structure, sample data and wanted result, you can use some of the online fiddle like https://www.db-fiddle.com/ to create [mre]. Welcome to SO.

Comment: You haven't posted all I asked for. Things I asked for are: I asked for table structure I asked it to see what kind of fields you are using, because  your date fields does not like like properly formatted MySQL date types, and its important to know that for you query. Second thing, please just post wanted result, you posted part of sample data, and from your description is not 100% clear to me what you need...